# Why is comparing the ".constructor" property of two windows unreliable?

Tags: javascript, constructor, cross-browser, window

I'm trying to understand why the following is not working as I would think it does. I'd like to check whether an object is a window. I was thinking that checking the constructors of the current window and another window would work.

So, first creating another window:

```
var popup = window.open('', '', '');
```

And then checking with:

```
popup.constructor === window.constructor;
```

But for some reason the results vary among browsers:

- IE7: Returns `true`

  - But that's simply because `.constructor === undefined`
- IE8: Returns `false`
- IE9: Throws an error with no text (`""`)
- Chrome: Returns `false`

  - Though in both cases `.constructor === DOMWindow` - but `DOMWindow` is not accessible directly like this
- Opera: Returns `false`

  - Though in both cases `.constructor === Object`
- Firefox: Returns `false`

  - Though in both cases `.constructor === Window`

Why isn't this reliable and working correctly? jQuery simply checks for `"setInterval" in window`, but I'd like to create a more robust function for checking whether an object is a window.

Comment: Window is defined in each instance of a page, so they are different. and this is good, because I don't want other sites inject my prototypes window.constructor.prototype.alert = function(){ /* some evil function */ };

Comment: strangely ie7 seems share the same prototype between two windows... as I said sounds insecure xD but maybe theres some sort of  xsite protection

Comment: Working with host objects is generally unreliable... it's not just the `constructor` property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every separate `window` is a separate global context for the interpreter (and yes I'm ignoring IE7 for the moment).  Your issue really becomes clear when you think about `instanceof`:

```
if (something instanceof Array) { ... }
```

The problems with that occur when "something" is a value that was constructed in a separate context, like an iframe for example.  Each window has it's very own copy of the "Array" constructor, so even though an object may be an Array instance, it's not an instance of the same constructor function.

I suspect that the IE7 behavior is related to some other weirdness that I *think* is something like `window.window` being not equal to `window`.  Like, one of them is in fact a reference to something internal. (Maybe it's `window` not being equal to `window.self` even though they otherwise behave identically. I don't invest a lot of philosophical thought time in contemplating IE7.)

Comment: LOL, yes, definitely closes the ie7 discussion... I'm asserting that window instanceof window.Math.random

Comment: I looked into IE and just for the record, in IE7/8, `window.window === window` but `window.self !== window`. In IE9 this seems to be fixed.

Comment: Wow thanks.  I've been busy lately and haven't so much as fired up a Windows VM in a week or so :-)