# Can't validate Object in Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

The object's values are fetched via:

```
const link = $("#link").val();
const state = $("#state").val(); etc...
```

The Object is then returned:

```
const departmentObject = {
  position,
  name,
  link,
  state,
  requirements: {
    age,
    citizenship,
    degree
  },
  salary,
  description
};
```

I pass the object to a follow-up function in which I am validating its contents. I'm having trouble validating this due to the object `requirements` inside the main object. I started with an IF statement:

```
let missingBoxes = [];
const array = Object.keys(departmentObject);
const subArray = Object.keys(departmentObject.requirements);

for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  keyname = array[i];
  if (departmentObject[keyname] !== "") {
    console.log("box not empty");
  } else {
    console.log("box empty, push to missingBoxes");
    missingBoxes.push(keyname);
  }
}
```

I then made a subArray to test for `departmentObject.requirements` independently, but obviously `requirements` is still in the original departmentObject. I need either one if statement for everything or two separate ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For validation of nested object you can use recursion within for Loop.

```
function check(obj){
    var keys = Object.keys(obj);
    var missingBoxes = [];
    for(let i=0; i<keys.length; i++){
        if(obj[keys[i]]!== ''){
            if(obj[keys[i]].constructor === {}.constructor){
                check(obj[keys[i]]);
             }
        }else{
            missingBoxes.push(keys[i]);
           console.log('blank')
         }
    }
    console.log(missingBoxes);

    }
```

Steps :

1. get keys out of Object
2. check if value of key is not bank
3. if yes then add it to missingBoxes array.
4. if no then check if this is an object.
5. if object call check method again.

Comment: check is not defined

Comment: first line function check is defining it. so this should not be an issue.
are you copying on function body. in that case you will get that error.

Comment: holy cow, this is working!! tweaking it a bit but I have all boxes in a clean array. Will definitely read up on recursive functions. Thank you @manoj-yadav

Comment: one question, i haven't seen the `.constructor === {}.constructor` before. What role does it play ?

Comment: to check type of value. you can find more on this here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7688070/why-is-comparing-the-constructor-property-of-two-windows-unreliable

and this one for more info.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion to handle the nested requirements object.

```js
function findMissingKeys(obj, keyPath = null, missingKeys = []) {  
  for(let key in obj) {
    if (typeof obj[key] === 'object') {
      findMissingKeys(obj[key], key, missingKeys)
    } else if (obj[key] === "") {
      if (keyPath) {
        missingKeys.push(`${keyPath}.${key}`);
      } else {
        missingKeys.push(key);
      }
    }
  }
  return missingKeys
}

function validateDepartment() {
  try {
    const textArea = document.getElementById("textArea")
    const departmentObject = JSON.parse(textArea.value)
    const missingKeys = findMissingKeys(departmentObject)
    console.log({ missingKeys })
  } catch(e) {
    alert(e)
  }
}

validateDepartment()
```

```html
<h4>Department Validator</h4>
<textarea id="textArea" cols=50 rows=10>
  {
    "position": "",
    "name": "",
    "link": "",
    "state": "",
    "requirements": {
      "age": "",
      "citizenship": "",
      "degree": ""
    },
    "salary": "",
    "description": ""
  }
</textarea>
<hr>
<button onclick="validateDepartment()">
  Validate
</button>
```

Comment: an explanation would help me greatly